# select another statement If no rows returned Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am weak at SQL. I have a small table with 3 columns and basic select statement.

```
    select intl, loc FROM test_table where p.country = 'UAE'
```

but in some cases there are no rows returned and in those cases I want to select another statement from the same table.

I found the below query but I cant get it to work.

```
    select intl, loc FROM test_table
    where p.country = 'UAE'
    union all
    select 'intl','Loc' from dual 
    where not exists ( select intl, loc FROM test_table where p.country = 'Other' )
```

I know its simple but I'm stuck for hours.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, a bit different approach may be this:

```
SELECT intl, loc from test_table WHERE p.country = 
(CASE WHEN (SELECT intl FROM test_table WHERE p.country='UAE' AND ROWNUM=1) IS NOT NULL THEN 'UAE' 
ELSE 'Other' END);
```

It looks like you want to use either one value in `WHERE p.country =` or another. So this `CASE` determines whether selecting with the first `p.country` value returns something (we have to limit the results with `ROWNUM=1` to get exactly one result, otherwise the case will not work - it expects one value after WHEN). If it does (`IS NOT NULL`), then we use that value in our `WHERE`, otherwise we use a different value specified after the `ELSE`.

Comment: Thanks. this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

The query you seem to want is:

```
select intl, loc 
from test_table
where p.country = 'UAE'
union all
select 'intl', 'Loc' from dual 
where not exists ( select intl, loc from test_table where p.country = 'UAE' );
```

The country for the `NOT EXISTS` should be the same as in the original query.

Comment: @ShB . . . That's very vague.

Answer (score 1):

```
select intl, loc 
from test_table
where p.country = 'UAE'
union all
select intl, loc from test_table 
where not exists ( select intl, loc from test_table where p.country = 'UAE' );
```

This is better.